# Path to existing file in root folder not found on Windows

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I extracted these 4 files in D:

```
train-images-idx3-ubyte
train-labels-idx1-ubyte 
t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/train-labels-idx1-ubyte'`
```

My code:

```
def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):
    """Load MNIST data from `path`"""
    path = "D:/"
    labels_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-labels-idx1-ubyte' % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-images-idx3-ubyte' % kind)

    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
        magic, n = struct.unpack('>II',
                                 lbpath.read(8))
        labels = np.fromfile(lbpath,
                             dtype=np.uint8)

    with open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
        magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII",
                                               imgpath.read(16))
        images = np.fromfile(imgpath,
                             dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(labels), 784)

    return images, labels
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/NN2.py", line 28, in <module>
    X_train, y_train = load_mnist('mnist/', kind='train')
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/NN2.py", line 14, in load_mnist
    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

This is originaly code from textbook:
https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/ch12/ch12.ipynb

Comment: Just did, sorry. Link contains authors' original code.

Comment: I bet this file has an extension that the Explorer doesn't show.

Comment: @ForceBru What does this imply?

Comment: the Explorer is showing you only _a part_ of the file's name, it doesn't show you the extension. So, `D:/stuff` doesn't exist, but `D:/stuff.extension` does. You can force the Explorer to show the extension in settings.

Comment: Tried it, same error.

Comment: please post the error message.

Comment: Completely identical to OP

Comment: have you now enabled the extensions display? What extension does the file have? Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: @ForceBru - I dowloaded and unziped the example files, and the names are correct, there's no extension.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/865219/how-to-show-or-hide-file-name-extensions-in-windows-explorer I did this. Files are directly on D disk. I don't know what is extension because nothing change in names of files I need. If I had to guess `.idx1-ubyte` ...but this was before I change settings so I relly don't know. Its really odd because I only have to se path to file, everything else should be done in original code from github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a path issue. How about navigating into your `D:` folder via the command line terminal, open a Python interpreter there, and do a

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

to show all the files & folders under `D:`. Then, you can check if train-labels-idx1-ubyte is indeed there and how it's spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6qc9t1/path_to_existing_file_in_root_folder_not_found_on/

It was typo hahah. Sorry to all, I just haven't noticed.

Comment: I had a look at the links, and the problem seems to be that the tool you used to decompress the .gz files changed the names of the files while extracting (mine behaved correctly and didn't). A lesson on this is: *Don't post images of text*. If you had pasted the filenames as text, we would have noticed that immediately and spared a lot of time. Or, at least, an image large enough to be readable would have helped. It will be better next time!